# CKEditor not showing special characters

Tags: textarea, ckeditor

I presently have CKeditor setup on a webpage, but strange things are happening when I attempt to use special HTML characters (such as `<` for example. Obviously, I want the whole thing to show up.

In the page source, I have the following

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="credit"><p>
    “The Carlu.” Web. 15 Oct. 2010. &lt;http://www.thecarlu.com/thecarlu.html&gt;.</p>
</textarea>
```

However, once CKEditor has loaded, I see the following in the editable section

> “The Carlu.” Web. 15 Oct. 2010. .

Whats going on here and how should this be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't there an option to treat CKEditor content as entity-encoded or something similar?

I suggest you try to play around with this parameters

```
CKEDITOR.config.htmlEncodeOutput
CKEDITOR.config.entities
```